Problems running "import-hbase.sh" file for metadata ingestion from hbase
I am running a Docker stack with the following containers:

atlas (Apache Atlas)
storm
cassandra
nimbus
kafka
hbase
zookeeper

Apache Atlas service is running and I have access to the user interface in localhost:21000, as is the case with hbase (localhost:16010). All containers (Atlas, HBase, Zookeeper, etc.) are in the same Docker network and can communicate with each other.
But when I run the import-hbase.sh command file in atlas, for the ingestion of hbase metadata by atlas, I get an error:
ERROR - [main:] ~ ImportHBaseEntities failed (HBaseBridge:198)
org.apache.atlas.AtlasException: Failed to load application properties
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:147)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:100)
    at org.apache.atlas.hbase.bridge.HBaseBridge.main(HBaseBridge.java:140)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConversionException: 'atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher' doesn't map to a List object: true, a java.lang.Boolean
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getList(AbstractConfiguration.java:1144)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getList(AbstractConfiguration.java:1109)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolatedConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1274)
    at org.apache.atlas.ApplicationProperties.get(ApplicationProperties.java:142)
    ... 2 more

The error seems to be related to the property "atlas.graph.index.search.solr.wait-searcher=true" in the atlas-application.properties file. It seems that instead of interpreting the value of this property as a Boolean, it is interpreted as an object of type List.
I have reviewed the atlas-application.properties file, even removed this statement and it still gives the same error.
Could anyone help me with this error?
Has anyone had any successful experience importing data from hbase or kafka etc. to Apache Atlas?
